# protobuf java toString printing no message type

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

The methods in TextFormat doesn't include the message type in the output for the supplied message which is very annoying. Feels like it's pretty important to easily see what type the message is (especially as I have messages with no fields).

Is it possible to fix that without writing wrappers yourself? (any 3rd party stuff available)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `message.getDescriptorForType().getFullName()` to get the type name. The descriptor also provides all kinds of other type information.